# Timeseries data : Pandas Dataframe merging/summing multiple dataframes on dates column with same + different data columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

So I've really searched hard to find solutions to this problem but nothing quite gets me the result I'm after.

I have hundreds of dataframes which represent timeseries data for a number of objects.  Each object can have ALL of the columns, some, or none.  Every object DF has a dates column and an index (that I'm not really using).

Basically I want to join the dataframes, and sum the columns.  I've simplified it down to this:

DF#1

| index | dates | 1000 | 1001 | 1002 | 1012 | 1014 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-31 | 1 | NaN | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-02 | 1 | 2 | NaN | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-02-03 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-02-04 | 2 | 3 | 1 | NaN | 1 |
| 5 | 2023-02-05 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2023-02-06 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-02-07 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

DF#2

| index | dates | 1000 | 1001 | 1003 | 1006 | 2001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-31 | 1 | NaN | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-02 | 1 | 2 | NaN | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-02-03 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-02-04 | 2 | 3 | 1 | NaN | 1 |
| 5 | 2023-02-05 | 3 | NaN | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2023-02-06 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-02-07 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

DF#3

| index | dates | 1000 | 1001 | 1003 | 1012 | 1014 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-31 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | 1 | NaN | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-02 | 1 | 2 | NaN | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-02-03 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-02-04 | 2 | 3 | 1 | NaN | 1 |
| 5 | 2023-02-05 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2023-02-06 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-02-07 | 4 | 5 | 1 | NaN | 1 |

RESULTANT DF

| index | dates | 1000 | 1001 | 1002 | 1003 | 1006 | 1012 | 1014 | 2001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-31 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | 3 | 2 | 10 | 20 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-02 | 3 | 6 | NaN | NaN | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-02-03 | 6 | 9 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-02-04 | 6 | 9 | 1 | 2 | NaN | NaN | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2023-02-05 | 9 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2023-02-06 | 12 | 12 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-02-07 | 12 | 15 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

ultimately I will be using plotly to graph individual objects trends for each column as well as the overall (hence needing to merge DFs).

I've tried various inner/outer joins on 'dates' with a pd.merge, but that just gets me hundreds of columns with _x _y appended, but at least the dates work.

I've tried using pd.concat to no avail.

I've used pd.concat(DF1, DF2).groupby('dates', as_index=False).sum() which works for columns as long as they exist in ALL dataframes, it doesn't when there is a mismatch.

I've also tried pd.merge with .sum(axis=1)

I'm basically at a brick wall :)

Comment: ugh, looks like SO nuked my MD formatting on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what is the problem with `pd.concat`?

On my toy example below all goes well:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dt':pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01'), 'a':[1], 'b':[2]})
df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'dt':pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01'), 'a':[234]})


pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).groupby('dt', as_index=False).sum()
```

results in:

```
dt=2023-01-01
a=235
b=2
```

Comment: This might go poorly....  Like you, on smaller datasets its fine, but when I actually run it on production data it only works for the first few iterations.

Here you can see the initial cumulative DF (already built up from the same loop and about 5 previous DFs).  Then we dump the next DF to concat in to the initial one.
The 3rd DF is the result of the concat line, which is :
`INITIAL_CUMULATIVE_DF = pd.concat([INTIIAL_CUMULATIVE_DF, DF_TO_BE_ADDED]).groupby('dates', as_index=False).sum()`

See screenshot in comment below for the output and confused resultant DF

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8ppwtmb

Comment: @SimonPlant, try converting types. Probably, pandas cannot concat dfs with int and float types. To further help you I need minimal reproducible example of problem, to test on local machine as toy example works well

Comment: Thanks.  I have no idea why theres a mix of int and float as int(thing) is specified when creating the  base DFs..... I've now forced everything to float and no change, I still only get a 2 column resultant DF out.  I'll try to generate a working toy example and reproduce here.